# How to ignore React.js source files in a clean Nest.js installation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, nestjs, tsconfig

I have a clean Nest.js installation and a folder called "client" with create-react-app clean installation in it.

Let's assume the project structure is:

```
./
  ...some Nest.js folders...
  client <- React.js is here
  ...some more Nest.js folders...
  tsconfig.json <- here the "client" folder is excluded in the "exclude" block
```

I'm trying to run `npm start:dev` inside the project root folder to make Nest.js compile all the files, but it keeps complaining "Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.".

[image: The error message]

*I've added the "client" folder to "exclude" block inside the tsconfig.json of Nest.js installation. **And I still keep having this error**!*

**What am I doing wrong? How to completely ignore the client files for the Nest.js compilation script?**

The tsconfig.json contents:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "client",
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Repro is really simple. Steps to reproduce:

1. Install globally Nest.js and create a fresh Nest.js installation

2. Create a folder "client" inside the installation folder

3. Install globally "create-react-app" tool and create a new React installation 
inside the "client" folder

4. Go to the project root folder and run "npm run start:dev" and look for the errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to exclude the folder in `tsconfig.build.json` too

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "test",
    "dist",
    "**/*spec.ts",
    "client"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Wow! That was near. Just what I've looked for! Thank you!